# Integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\cos^4{(x)} + \sin^2{(2x)}}\, dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How to evaluate this integral:
> $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\cos^4{(x)} + \sin^2{(2x)}}\, dx.$$

I can take the $\cos(x)$ out of the square root by expanding $\sin(2x)$ so it becomes $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(x) \sqrt{\cos^2(x) +4\sin^2(x)} \, dx$$
but still I have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: Hint: turn the $\cos^2$ into a $\sin^2$ and you're done. Then either let $\sqrt{3}\sin x = \tan t$ or $\sqrt{3}\sin x = \sinh t$. The second one, however, will be easier than the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed as
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos x\sqrt{\cos^2{(x)} + 4\sin^2{(x)}}\quad dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos x\sqrt{1-\sin^2{(x)} + 4\sin^2{(x)}}\quad dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos x\sqrt{1+ 3\sin^2{(x)}}\quad dx$$
Let $\sin x=\frac{t}{\sqrt 3}\implies \cos x\ dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}dt$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3} \sqrt{1+ t^2} dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Use subsitution $\sin(x)=t $

$$\int_0^{π/2} \cos(x) \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}\, dx\ =\ \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+3t^2}\,dt$$